# Windows 10 Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: networking

I have a PC running on Windows 10 with which I am very pleased. On my old PC I installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS with which I am also very pleased. I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux but at one time I was familiar with DOS which I was advised would help me with Linux but the learning process for me is slow.

I would like these computers to be able to share folders over my wireless network. Windows has provided me with a name for the network and a password. Other peripherals are recognised and share the Windows PC folders.

When I browse the network on Ubuntu I can see my Windows PC, my Ubuntu PC and a windows network folder. No matter what I do I cannot connect to the network and share folders nor is my Ubuntu PC recognised In Windows. I installed Samba but I cant find it to configure even if I knew how to do so.

I am very much still stuck in Windows mode and I would be very grateful for some help please.

Answer (score 0):

first check  network discovery is turn on , if so
then type smb://IP ADDRESS of system you want to connect, I popup will open asking USERNAME AND PASSWORD

Comment: I am a complete novice. How do I check if network discovery is on. I am connected to a network through a router so I assume it must be on. I got a pop up when I clicked on my Windows PC icon but nothing I typed was accepted. I tried what you suggested but an error came back as no such directory. I have now lost the Windows PC icon although the Ubuntu  icon remains.

Comment: I disabled the password option from Windows 10 and my Ubuntu PC can now connect to the public folder of my Windows PC. I have no idea why the password or user was not recognised when I tried to log on but this seems to be a fix although I would still prefer password protection.

Comment: Sadly this fix is a bit of a bodge as the public directory is not the same as used by other peripheral devices and it only works one way in that Ubuntu can see and share public files with Windows 10 but not the other way around. I will endeavour to help myself but nothing seems very straightforward or even user friendly in Ubuntu. I would assume that all Linux operating systems work in much the same way.